# How to programmatically disable caching when user goes back in UC Browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, uc-browser

UC Browser loads a saved page when user clicks on back button. I want previous page to refresh on back button action so that controls such as checkboxes get restored to default state. I want to control it programmatically in HTML or JavaScript. Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Comment: Have a look at that ^ linked question.  It should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should help:

```
location.reload(true);
```

> forcedReload Optional
>       Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified,
>   the browser may reload the page from its cache.

from [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't work for UC Browser. The previous page does not unload from the window in UC, it remains open. When user clicks back button, the previous page is simply shown in the foreground. I want to prevent that.

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button